# O uso do sujeito preposicionado é válido na norma culta?

Tags: preposições, sujeito

Ao ler grandes obras, é muito comum encontrar o sujeito separado de uma preposição.

**Exemplos:**

> "Não se surpreenda pelo fato *de eu* ter dito: É necessário que vocês nasçam de novo." — *João 3:7*

> "Sucedeu que, ao tempo *de ela* dar à luz, havia gêmeos em seu ventre;" — *Gênesis 38:27*

---

Como podem observar, os sujeitos estão separados da preposição. Ao invés de usar *ao tempo dela dar à luz*, utiliza-se *ao tempo de ela ...*.

Há uma regra que pede a separação entre preposição e sujeito? As frases abaixo estão de acordo com a norma culta?

> Apesar *dela* estar com raiva, fomos à festa.
>
> Apesar *de ela* estar com raiva, fomos à festa.

Comment: Na língua escrita, eu diria "apesar de ela **estar** com raiva, fomos à festa"  Eu não usaria "dela/dele" nesses casos, e nem penso que esteja correto.  Espero que alguém aqui me tire essa dúvida.  Já na língua falada, é muito comum a junção das duas palavras.

Comment: Mas... o sujeito da frase não seria "nós" (que fomos a festa) ?

Comment: @Centaurus grato pela dica do verbo. Já corrigir. Ao meu ver, há dois sujeitos: *ela* e *nós (oculto)*.

Comment: Pelo que li, boa parte dos gramáticos abominam a contração do sujeito + preposição, mas gramáticos como Evanildo Bechara, não desaprovam esta prática.

Answer (score 3):

Há uma regra na gramática normativa que pede a não contração do sujeito dos verbos no infinitivo com preposições, entretanto esta regra não é rígida. Gramáticos como *Evanildo Bechara*, *Rocha Lima* e *Adriano da Gama Kury* não desaprovam a contração do sujeito de verbo no infinitivo + preposições.

O professor Rocha Lima afirma, na *Gramática normativa da língua portuguesa (2011, p. 366)*, que o reger de preposição o sujeito (oração subordinada substantiva subjetiva) vem dos tempos mais antigos do idioma, embora contrarie a gramática ortodoxa.

A base para esta afirmação é um trecho da obra *O livro de Esopo: fabulario português medieval*, descoberto e publicado em *1906*:

> “A mym praz mais de comer trijguo... que gallinhas.”

De acordo com a *Moderna Gramática Portuguesa (2012, p. 459)*, "a possibilidade de se pôr o sujeito de infinitivo antes ou depois desta forma verbal nos permite dizer":

> Está na hora **de** beber **a** onça água *(posição rara)*
>   Está na hora **de a** onça beber água *(posição frequente)*
>   Está na hora **da** onça beber água *(posição mais frequente)*

No último exemplo, temos os vocábulos *de* (preposição) e o *a* (artigo) que, na língua falada, são comumente contraídos, seja por hábito ou eufonia, formando a expressão *da*. Por isso, segundo o gramático, essa construção "não tem repugnado os ouvidos dos que melhor conhecem e escrevem a língua portuguesa" e, portanto, haveria nenhum problema com a contração.

Para o professor Cláudio Moreno, na escrita temos a liberdade de escrever com, ou sem, a contração, porém — na fala — a contração é obrigatória. Segundo o professor, "Infelizmente, a regrinha [da não contração] já está tão arraigada nos manuais de redação da imprensa brasileira que será impossível eliminar o seu emprego"

No Brasil, os atos oficiais e de processo legislativo da Presidência da República Federativa do Brasil utilizam o *Manual de Redação da Presidência da República* como diretriz na construção da literatura redacional. Este manual segue a regra utilizada pela gramática normativa, ou seja, devem ser evitadas construções com o sujeito preposicionado.

> *Errado:* É tempo **do** Congresso votar a emenda.
>   *Certo:* É tempo **de o** Congresso votar a emenda.

> *Errado:* Apesar **da** Assessoria ter informado em tempo, (...).
>   *Certo:* Apesar **de a** Assessoria ter informado em tempo, (...)

NETO (2003) explica construções como “de o” e “de ele” da seguinte forma:

> Pense na seguinte frase: “No caso *de* se alterar **o cenário**...” Qual é o sujeito do infinitivo “alterar”? Só pode ser o que se altera, ou seja, “o cenário”. Você percebeu que esse sujeito apareceu depois do verbo. Percebeu também que estão presentes as palavras “de” e “o”, separadas: “No caso *de* se alterar **o cenário**...”. Na frase em questão, o sujeito é posposto, isto é, vem depois do verbo. E se fosse anteposto? Seria possível pura e simplesmente alterar a ordem das palavras: “No caso *de* **o cenário** se alterar”. A forma “de o” se explica
>   pelo fato de a preposição não fazer parte do sujeito. (NETO, 2003, p.70)

Numa análise¹ feita no artigo *Sujeito Preposicionado em Orações Reduzidas de Infinitivo: Descrição e Prescrição*, registrou-se um total de 199 ocorrências de Sujeito preposicionado em orações reduzidas de infinitivo em teses e dissertações nas áreas de Exatas e Humanas, assim distribuídas:

```
┌────────┬────────────┬─────────────┐
│ Norma  │ Ocorrência │ Porcentagem │
├────────┼────────────┼─────────────┤
│ Padrão │ 138        │ 69,3%       │
├────────┼────────────┼─────────────┤
│ Culta  │ 61         │ 30,7%       │
├────────┼────────────┼─────────────┤
│ Total  │ 199        │ 100%        │
└────────┴────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Por conseguinte, para a grande maioria dos gramáticos, professores e graduados — sob monitoramento, ambas frases estão corretas; No entanto, se tu fores prestar concurso público ou redigir um ato do poder público, não deverás utilizar a contração entre preposição e sujeito de verbo no infinitivo.

***Referências***

<sup>REPÚBLICA, Presidência da. **Manual de Redação da Presidência da República.** [S. l.], 27

   dez. 2018. Disponível em: http://www4.planalto.gov.br/centrodeestudos/assuntos/manual-deredacao-da-presidencia-da-republica/manual-de-redacao.pdf. Acesso em: 14 mar. 2019.</sup>

   <sup>BECHARA, Evanildo. **Moderna gramática portuguesa.** 37. ed. [S. l.]: Lucerna, 2003. 671 p.

   ISBN 9788521023180.</sup>

   <sup>LIMA, Rocha. **Gramática normativa da língua portuguesa.** 49. ed. rev. [S. l.]: José Olympio,

    2011. 659 p. ISBN 9788503010221.</sup>

   <sup>O RATO da cidade e o da aldeia. In: O LIVRO de Esopo. Revista Lusitana: [s. n.], 1906. Disponível em: https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/O_Livro_de_Esopo/O_rato_da_cidade_e_o_da_aldeia. Acesso em: 14 mar. 2019.</sup>

   <sup>NETO, Pasquale Cipro. **Está na hora de a (da) onça beber água.** [S. l.], 24 nov. 2011.

   Disponível em: https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/cotidian/ff2411200503.htm. Acesso em: 14

   mar. 2019.</sup>

   <sup>NOGUEIRA, Sérgio. DELE ou DE ELE?. In: NOGUEIRA, Sérgio. **Temas polêmicos.** [S. l.], 20

   out. 2010. Disponível em: http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/temaspolemicos-6.html. Acesso em: 14 mar. 2019.</sup>
   <sup>ANJOS, Marcelo Alessandro Limeira dos; REIS, M. E. C. ; OLIVEIRA, M. S. . **Sujeito preposicionado em orações reduzidas de infinitivo: descrição e prescrição.** Web-Revista SOCIODIALETO, v. 4, p. 525, 2014.</sup>
   <sup>NETO, Pasquale Cipro. **Nossa língua em letra e música.** São Paulo: Publifolha, 2003</sup>

---

<sup>¹ Análise feita pelo professor Dr. Marcelo Alessandro Limeira dos Anjos; pelas Mestra em Letras Meryane Sousa Oliveira e Graduada Maria Eduarda Carvalho dos Reis</sup>

Comment: "*“A mym praz mais de comer trijguo... que gallinhas.*” - Certo, porém é preciso notar que o sujeito dessa frase é oracional, "comer trigo".

Answer (score 1):

Veja que o que está preposicionado no exemplo que você dá,

> Apesar de ela estar com raiva, fomos à festa.

não é o sujeito, é a oração inteira.

É por isso que a norma culta recomenda a separação. Se dissermos "apesar dela estar com raiva, fomos à festa", a fronteira entre as duas orações passaria por dentro de uma palavra ("dela").

Assim, ao usar o registro padrão, recomenda-se fortemente o uso da preposição separada do pronome.

Nos registros coloquial e popular? Não tenho tanta certeza. Como você fala?

> Apesar /dɛlɐjstaʁ/ com raiva

ou

> Apesar /dʒjɛlɐjstaʁ/ com raiva?

Eu tenderia a pronunciar da segunda forma, acho. Mas com certeza ouço pessoas usando a primeira. E creio que às vezes faço o mesmo.

Comment: Segundo uma aula do Professor Adriano Paciello, "ela" é sujeito do verbo "estar", por isso — segundo ele — não deve haver a contração. Mas, segundo uma pesquisa que fiz, a regra é opcional para muitos gramáticos. Acho que a conclusão é: Textos de atos do poder público e jornalístico = sem a contração; demais textos = opcional.

Comment: Não sei se a fala -- /dɛlɐjstaʁ/ versus /dʒjɛlɐjstaʁ/ -- é um bom critério: nós escrevemos *anel de ouro*, mas dizemos, pelo menos eu digo, /doru/; e *fico à espera* mas digo /fikaʃpɛrɐ/.