# Devo recorrer à contração ou à forma extensa?

Tags: frases, contrações

No que toca a contrações, como consigo saber se a sua forma extensa é equivalente e/ou se deva usar uma forma em detrimento da outra?

Deixo um exemplo prático, com o qual me deparei, que pode ser utilizado para a reflexão/resposta:

> "A seguinte situação permite poupar tempo às pessoas e pode aumentar a
>   capacidade **destas** conseguirem perceber as relações associadas."

Neste caso, a utilização das palavras `de esta` ou `desta` é igual, ou deva utilizar uma em específico?

Comment: como falante PT-BR, não lembro de utilizar "de esta".

Comment: Eu utilizaria *de estas*. Motivo: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5861/o-uso-do-sujeito-preposicionado-%c3%a9-v%c3%a1lido-na-norma-culta

Comment: Uma coisa é falar, outra é escrever. O uso formal aqui seria: de esta. Que seja Brasil ou Portugal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No exemplo apresentado, deverá ser utilizado, definitivamente, a preposição `de` e o pronome demonstrativo `estas`, sem contracção.

Assim, a forma correcta da frase será:

> A seguinte situação permite poupar tempo às pessoas e pode aumentar a
>   capacidade **de estas** conseguirem perceber as relações associadas.

Da mesma maneira, diz-se, por exemplo:

> O facto **de ele** ser português contribuiu para a compreensão da
>   frase

E não:

> O facto **dele** ser português contribuiu para a compreensão da frase.

Como leitura complementar sugiro [esta partilha do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/preposicao-seguida-de-artigo-definido-sem-contracao/32586).

Comment: Eu estava respondendo ao Peixoto. A sua resposta está perfeita.