# Quando usar "apesar de o" e "apesar do"?

Tags: preposições, regência-verbal, locuções-adverbias

Creio que neste caso específico, não se trate apenas da regência verbal, mas não tenho certeza.  A minha pergunta é porque, **na norma culta**, usamos **"de + o"** no primeiro exemplo e **"do"** no segundo exemplo.

1. Apesar **de o tempo estar chuvoso**, decidimos viajar naquele dia.
2. Apesar **do tempo chuvoso**, decidimos viajar naquele dia.

Por acaso as duas formas ("de + o" e "do") estariam corretas em ambos os casos?

Podemos ainda dizer "apesar de que o tempo estava chuvoso..." e, neste caso não há dúvida.

**Minha pergunta refere-se a este caso específico**, o da locução advérbial "apesar de".

Comment: 1) Temos um verbo no infinitivo; logo, o sujeito (o tempo) não pode ser preposicionado. 2) Não há sujeito; portanto, a contração é possível. Para uma resposta mais completa, basta acessar a pergunta [O uso do sujeito preposicionado é válido na norma culta?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5866/2759)