# "Tenho medo dela não aceitar." ou "Tenho medo de ela não aceitar."?

Tags: preposições, contrações

Existe alguma regra para se fazer a contração de uma preposição com artigo ou pronome ?

Pessoalmente, eu tento falar da forma que me soa correto. Por exemplo:

> - Independente **de o** que eles possam querer, nós já decidimos... (sempre falo)
> - Estou intrigado com o fato **de ele** nunca ter se pronunciado a respeito....(sempre falo)
> - Ele chegou um pouco antes **de a** festa começar. (sei que o correto é assim, mas falo "antes **da** festa")
> - Está na hora **de as** crianças irem dormir. (idem ao anterior, eu digo "**das** crianças" embora ache que está errado)
> - Apesar **de a** maioria da população odiar o presidente... (também acho que falo errrado, eu digo "**da** maioria)

No entanto, sempre faço a contração em:

> - Tenho algumas dúvidas a respeito **do** uso do verbo haver.
> - Pretendo ir à casa **dos** meus avós amanhã.
> - A despeito **do** que você possa dizer, eu já decidi que... (quanto a esse último, não tenho certeza quanto à forma correta.)

Aparentemente, na maioria das vezes eu sei quando fazer a contração ou não, mas não sei porque. Faço-o por ter tido muito contato com algumas pessoas que têm grande conhecimento da língua portuguesa e isso ficou absorvido.
Então, o que eu pergunto é: **existe alguma regra para se fazer ou não a contração da preposição com um artigo definido ou pronome?**  Existem exceções a tal regra?  **E os artigos indefinidos, como ficam?**  (de um = dum, de um = duma)

A pergunta refere-se principalmente à língua falada.

Comment: Resposta: [O uso do sujeito preposicionado é válido na norma culta?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5861/2759)

Comment: Há um impasse entre os gramáticos, mas, em regra, não se utiliza a contração da preposição com o sujeito, no entanto, pode ocorrer em complementos nominais, verbais etc, por exemplo: Independente de o que eles possam [correto], Independente do que eles possam [correto]; antes de a festa começar [errado], antes de a festa começar [correto].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [O uso do sujeito preposicionado é válido na norma culta?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5861/o-uso-do-sujeito-preposicionado-%c3%a9-v%c3%a1lido-na-norma-culta)

Comment: @Schilive   Nope.

Comment: @Centaurus, se não te for incômodo responder, não responde porque a tua pergunta se refere à língua falada?

Comment: @Schilive  Porque é onde eu tenho minhas dúvidas.

Comment: @Centaurus, onde = língua falada?

Comment: Na língua falada, nunca vi alguém problema em contrair ou até em criar contrações, como “ele gostar d'eu sofrendo”. Interessante que “tenho medo de o João comer maçã com cianeto” não me soa errada ou inatural, mas “tenho medo de o João” me soa inatural, mas não errada. Isso pode ser por costume de ler sempre coisas formais, mas não sei. Em relação à fala do Brasil, creio que se figuras formalíssimas, como o Presidente da República, falarem assim, é formal qualquer um falar assim. >>

Comment: >> Então, na minha opinião, se o Sr. Lula, Sua Excelência, Presidente da República, Bolsonaro, Sra. Dilma e o Sr. Fernando Henrique Cardoso falarem assim em situações formalíssimas, como em discursos transmitidos pela TV, é formal qualquer um usar contrações. Para mim 1 já bastaria, mas 4 seria para garantir.

Answer (score -1):

A contração dela nesse caso seria incorreta, pois dela é pronome possessivo:

"O carro dela."

Isso é arcaico, mas para se evitar ambiguidade pode-se usar:

Tenho medo d'ela não aceitar.

A forma não contraída é sempre correta:

- Tenho medo de o bicho papão. (Embora soe estranho está correta)

Antigamente com a impressora de tipo era interessante economizar caracteres, pois era muito trabalhoso montar as matrizes de tipo, hoje em dia você pode perder três segundos por dia e escrever a forma não contraída.

Comment: Bom dia.  Eu me refiro principalmente à língua falada.

Comment: Editei e acrescentei.

Comment: Mais ou menos. *Vide* Base XVIII de http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2007-2010/2008/decreto/d6583.htm.